# How to add Audio tag in ng-grid cell template

Tags: angularjs, audio

I am new to angular Js. I am using ng-grid to list dynamic data. I have audio,video,image as data. When there is only images as data it is appearing properly . How to set audio and video tag in cell template.
Currently i am getting an error.

```
scope.pinsview = {
        data: 'userlist',

        columnDefs: [
        {field:'image_name',
        displayName:'Pin', 
        cellTemplate:'<div ng-switch="row.getProperty(\'pin_type\')">'+
                  '<div ng-switch-when="image"><img  src="/uploads/pins/images/{{row.getProperty(\'image_name\')[0]}}" /></div>' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when="audio"> <audio src="/uploads/pins/audio/{{row.getProperty(\'audio_file\')}}"> </div>' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when="video"><video src="/uploads/pins/videos/{{row.getProperty(\'video_id\')}}"></div>' +
                  '</div>'

            },
            {field: 'description', displayName: 'Pin'},
            {field: 'user_id.username', displayName: 'Pinned By'},
            {field: 'board_id.board_name', displayName: 'Pinned On'},
            {field: 'Actions', cellTemplate:
                        '<a ng-click="deletePin(row.entity)" class="btn btn-mini tip deleteAdmin"  confirmation-needed="Are you sure want to delete this group?" data-original-title="Delete"><img alt="" src="/assets/images/admin/icons/fugue/cross.png"></a>  <a class="btn btn-mini tip pwdReset" ng-click="blockPin(row.entity)" data-original-title="Reset Password"><img alt="" src="/assets/images/admin/icons/fugue/flag-black.png"></a>'}],
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    };
```

I am getting this error in my browser console

```
17angular.js:12332 Error: [$interpolate:noconcat] Error while interpolating: /uploads/pins/audio/{{row.getProperty('audio_file')}}
Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.
```

Can anybody help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.